# Change drop down selected item based on selected item of another drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have two drop down lists on my ASP.NET MVC 3. When one of the drop down lists is set to "Sole Proprietor", the other needs to be set to the same.

I'm sure the JavaScript, or jQuery, is very simple for something like this, however I am having a hard time finding a good example on the web since I am populating the drop down lists manually instead of through the controller.

Can someone either help me out with the code or point me to a good resource?

```
<select id="ProducerType" name="nmf" style="float:left;">
    <option value="Principal">Principal</option>
    <option value="Producer">Producer</option>
    <option value="SoleProprietor">Sole Proprietor</option>                
</select>

<select id="Role" name="nmf" style="float:left;">
    <option value="Agent">Agent</option>
    <option value="Financial Advisor">Financial Advisor</option>
    <option value="Platform">Platform</option>
    <option value="Principla_Owner">Principal/Owner</option>
    <option value="Registered Rep">Registered Rep</option>
    <option value="Sole Proprietor">Sole Proprietor</option>              
</select>
```

Comment: @PaoloMoretti - Although it is implied from asp.net mvc, the OP in fact never mentioned it. Perhaps they removed it from their project.

Comment: @TravisJ He mentioned jQuery in the second paragraph of his question. NealR feel free to remove the jQuery tag if you are expecting an answer with vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jsFiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/9GZQ2/

I set both dropdown values to `"Sole Proprietor"` your code has the space missing in the `ProducerType` select

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#ProducerType").change(function(){
           var value=$(this).val();
           if(value=="Sole Proprietor") $("#Role").val(value);
        });
        $("#Role").change(function(){
           var value=$(this).val();
           if(value=="Sole Proprietor") $("#ProducerType").val(value);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do I need to set and onClick/onSelectedItem or some such property for the drop down lists?

Comment: That is handled by jQuery when you call `.change()` on the element jquery links the function you send as a parameter to `.change()` as the event that will be fired.

Comment: Sorry, I am brand new to jQuery/Javaascript. Does this need to be inside of the <script type="text/jscript"> or some other such tag? I can see that it works in the fiddle but I can't get it to work on my machine..

Comment: Ugh.. still doesn't work (I just copied and pasted the code from your answer). Any idea where I should look?

Comment: I didn't remove the `t`  could that be it? I'm updating it now.

Comment: No, I caught that a minute ago (both of them).

Comment: Did you change both so that the value has a space in it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23814/discussion-between-michael-b-and-nealr)

Comment: Nevermind, wound up finding another typo that was causing the error (it's friday...). thank you very much for your help!