# By selecting from dropdown, enable another dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I am trying to build a form similar to all the online car brokers (i.e. autotrader, etc). By that I mean, I want to have selects for 'Make', 'Model', and 'Year'. I would like Model and Year to be disabled until a user selects the 'make' of their vehicle, thus getting the value from 'make' and changing the 'model' select box to only models for that make. And then the same for 'years' and so on.

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <select id="make" class="form-control">
                    <option>Make</option>
                    <option>Chevrolet</option>
                    <option>Ford</option>
                    <option>Toyota</option>
                    <option>GMC</option>
                </select>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <select id="models" class="form-control models" disabled>
                    <option>Model</option>

                </select> 
       </div>
```

This is my javascript. In the head of my html. However, the javascript does not run correctly in my html file.

```
    <script type='text/javascript'> 

     $(function(){
    //setup arrays
    Chevrolet = ['Silverado','Suburban','Tahoe'];
    Ford = ['F150','Taurus','Pinto','Bronco'];
    Toyota = ['Camry','Tacoma','4Runner'];
    GMC = ['blah1','blah2','blah3'];

    $('#make').change(function() {
        $('#models').prop('disabled', true);
        $("#models").html(""); //clear existing options
        var newOptions = window[this.value]; //finds the array w/the name of the selected value
        //populate the new options
        for (var i=0; i<newOptions.length; i++) {
            $("#models").append("<option>"+newOptions[i]+"</option>");
        }
        $('#models').prop('disabled', false); //enable the dropdown
        });
         });  

    </script>
```

I have started a basic jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/rynslmns/N9XTZ/1/

Comment: Check this stackoverflow answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14655978/1873002

Comment: im not sure thats what i am looking for.. for this example there will be 4 groups of models for each make. when you select the make (i.e. chevrolet) only that model group would appear in the next select box. i just need to know how to hide options from the 'model' select box depending on which 'make' the user selects.

Comment: so you need to use ajax to call your server side method with the selected item and to update the next select box with the ajax call result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of two things:

1. you can setup some arrays in javascript that are prepopulated with the values
2. you can write some ajax calls to your server that would retrieve the values based on what your database holds.

Here's an example that implements the first method, which is probably a good place for you to start.

http://jsfiddle.net/N9XTZ/6/

```
Chevrolet = ['Silverado','Suburban','Tahoe'];
Ford = ['F150','Taurus','Pinto','Bronco'];
Toyota = ['Camry','Tacoma','4Runner'];
GMC = ['blah1','blah2','blah3'];

$('#make').change(function() {
    $('#models').prop('disabled', true);
    $("#models").html(""); //clear out the existing selections
    var newOptions = window[this.value];
    //populate the new selections
    for (var i=0; i<newOptions.length; i++) {
        $("#models").append("<option>"+newOptions[i]+"</option>");
    }
    //enable the dropdown
    $('#models').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

I didn't prettify it, nor am I using all best practices (caching DOM selections, localizing variables, etc).  But it does what you're looking for, and you can play around with it a bit.

Note: this is an extension of Krishna's fiddle, so credit to him for getting the first part set up.  I think, however, that I've added the part you were really looking for.

Comment: beautiful. Exactly what I was looking for. If I wanted to embed this into my current html, would i just throw <script> tags around this?

Comment: when I put the code into the head of my html, the javascript does not work. I copied it exactly as it is on the results page of the JSFIDDLE. any suggestions?

Comment: Did you give your HTML elements the appropriate IDs? `make` and `models`?  Put the code above after the jQuery entry?

Comment: I entered the code above. I think it may have to do with the initial function call, but I am just learning js basics so I am not sure.