# Debugging dropdown menus and display user form inputs on same page

Tags: php, html, forms, input

Good morning everyone:

I would be grateful if some folks could give me some pointers on a web-based file planning system I'm developing.  I work for a division within a gov't agency that handles records management.  We work with the various other divisions within the agency to help them develop file plans so they are compliant with federal laws and regulations regarding records retention.  We are currently using an Access database that each division downloads to enter the names of various folders and then assign certain other characteristics.  My division wants to move away from the Access platform to a proper web-based application.  I have an extensive background with building SQL db's in MySQL, SQL Server, etc for analysis purposes.  And, I've worked with PHP sporadically over the last several years so I'm not exactly a noobie but I'm not an expert either so I could use some help troubleshooting some code.

Here's an overview of how this system needs to work.  The user will enter a folder name in a text box and then assign other characteristics to the folder by making selections out of a series of dropdown boxes.  They are:

media type: paper, dvd/cd, floppy disk, other
classification type: unclassified, confidential, secret, top secret
Disposition:  Same As Sub Series

Those last three were easy.  I successfully wrote the while and mysql_fetch_arrays to retrieve them from their tables in the db and display as drop down selections.

Now here's the first tricky part.  The user has to assign a Group, File Series and Sub File Series where Group is the highest level, File Series the next level and Sub File Series the most granular.  This would look like Group 100 Admin Files ---> File Series 101 Personnel Files---> Sub File Series 101-01 Supervisor Review Files. In the Sub File Series table there 715 selections.  The current Access db requires the user to click through all 715 permutations to find the relevant sub file series and this is the biggest complaint of the Access db.  So to aid the user in the new system, I want to use a series of dependent drop down menus so the user can start at the highest level to make selection which will then populate the mid-level with only the file series for that group and then populate the bottom level with sub file series associated only with the previous file series selection.  I was able to get this to work, too.

But here's my two problems.  I need to be able to display the user's selections on the same page very much like a shopping cart where the user can edit or delete the folder name and the underlying selections.  I have an include statement in my index.php script that's intended to do that but it's not working.  When the user clicks submit it displays the user input in a new page and I really need it to be displayed on the same page as the form...preferrably to the right of the form.  My second problem is when the user clicks submit and the browser goes to the new page to display the user inputs it displays all the user inputs/selections correctly except for the Sub File Series.  Instead of displaying the sub file series it only displays a duplicate of the mid-level choice: file series.  Here's what it should look like

File Name:  Folder1
Media Type:  dvd/cd
Classification Type: top secret
Disposition Type:  Same As Sub Series
Group Name: 100-Administration Files
File Series:  101-Personnel Files
Sub File Series:  101-01 Supervisor Review Files

Here's the flawed output

File Name:  Folder1
Media Type:  dvd/cd
Classification Type: top secret
Disposition Type:  Same As Sub Series
Group Name: 100
File Series:  101
Sub File Series:  101

Here's my code.  Please excuse any small typographical errors.  I had to manually transcribe this code as it's on a different server.  If there are small errors they probably aren't causing the problem I need to fix.  Thanks to everyone for any pointers you can give.  I know my code may look a bit ragged and amateur to all the old salty developers on this site so be gentle with me. :)

```
index.php

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<head>
<title>File Entry</title>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<style type ="text/css">
body {

        font-family:arial;
        color:#010DF;

}

form select{
            padding:5px;
            border:1px solid:#aaa;
            border-radius:4px;
            width:400px;
}

form label{
            font-size:12px;
            font-weight:bold;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        load_options('','Group');
});


function load_options(id,index){
        $("#loading").show();
        if(index=="FileSeries"){
                $("#SubFileSeries").html('<option value="">Select SubFileSeries</option>');
                }
                $.ajax({
                            url: "ajax.php?index=+index+"&id="+id,
                            complete: function(){$("#loading").hide():},
                            success: function(data) {
                                $("#"+index).html(data);
                        }

                })

}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="width:2000px; margin: auto; padding-top:100px;">

<form action="SendUserSelectionsToArray.php" method="post">

<p>Folder Name: <input type = "text" name = "Foldername1"/></p>

<p><label>Select Media type</label>

<?php

mysql_connect('localhost','fakename1','fakepassword1') or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db('csc') or die("Connection Failed");

$query = "SELECT media_type FROM Media";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>

<select name="selectMediaType1">
<?php

while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?>



<option value = "<?php echo $line['media_type'];?>"> <?php echo $line['media_type'];?></option>

<?php
}
?>

</select>
</p>

<p><label>Select Media type</label>

<?php

mysql_connect('localhost','fakename1','fakepassword1') or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db('csc') or die("Connection Failed");

$query = "SELECT classification_type FROM Classification";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>

<select name="classificationType1">
<?php

while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?>



<option value = "<?php echo $line['classification_type'];?>"> <?php echo $line['classification_type'];?></option>

<?php
}
?>

</select>
</p>

<p><label>Select Media type</label>

<?php

mysql_connect('localhost','fakename1','fakepassword1') or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db('csc') or die("Connection Failed");

$query = "SELECT dispostion_type FROM disposition";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>

<select name="dispositionType1">
<?php

while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?>



<option value = "<?php echo $line['disposition_type'];?>"> <?php echo $line['disposition_type'];?></option>

<?php
}
?>

</select>
</p>

<p><label>Select Group</label></p>
<p><select name="Group1" id="Group" onchange="load_options(this.value, 'FileSeries');"><option value="">Select Group</option>
</select></p>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<p><label>Select File Series</label></p>
<p><select name="FileSeries1" id="FileSeries" onchange="load_options(this.value, 'SubFileSeries');"><option value="">Select File Series</option>
</select></p>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<p><label>Select Sub File Series</label></p>
<p><select name="SubFileSeries1" id="SubFileSeries"><option value="">Select Group</option>
</select></p>

<img src="loader.gif" id="loading" align="absmiddle" style="display:none'"/>

<p>input type = "submit" id="sendtoarray" value="Submit and Enter Another Folder/></p>

</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<?php

include('SendUserSelectionsToArray.php');

?>

ajax.php

<?php

    class AJAX {

                private $database = NULL;
                private $_query = NULL;
                private $_fields = array();
                private $_index = NULL;
                const DB_HOST = 'localhost';
                const DB_USER = 'fakeuser1';
                const DB_PASSWORD = 'fakepassword1';
                const DB_NAME = 'csc';

                public function __construct() {
                        $this -> db_connect();
                //initiate database connection
                            $this->process_data();
                    }

                //Connect to database

                private function db_connect(){
                    $this->database = mysql_connect(self::DB_HOST, self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASSWORD);
                                if($this->database) {
                                        $db = mysql_select_db(self::DB_NAME, $this-> database);
                                        } else {
                                                echo mysql_error();die;
                                            }
                                    }

                                private function process_data(){
                                    $this->_index=($_REQUEST['index'])?$_REQUEST['index']:NULL;
                                    $id = f($_REQUEST['id'])?$_REQUEST['id']:NULL;
                                    switch($this->_index) {

                                    case 'Group':
                                            $this->_query = "SELECT * FROM groups";
                                            $this->_fields = array('id,'group_display_title');

                                            break;

                                    case 'FileSeries':
                                            $this->_query = "SELECT * FROM file_series WHERE group_id=$id";
                                            $this->_fields = array('file_series_id','file_series_name');

                                            break;

                                    case 'SubFileSeries':
                                            $this->_query = "SELECT * FROM sub_file_series WHERE file_series_id=$id";
                                            $this->_fields = "array('file_series_id','sub_file_series_name');

                                            break;

                                    default:  break;

                                    }
                                    $this->show_result();

                                    }

                                    public function show_result() {

                                        echo '<option value="">Select'.$this->_index.'</option>";

                                        $query = mysql_query($this->_query);
                                        while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                                                $entity_id = $result[$this->fields[0]];
                                                $enity_name = $result[$this->_fields[1]];
                                                echo "<option value='$entity_id'>$enity_name</option>";

                                                }

                                            }

                                        }

                                        $obj = new AJAX;

?>

senduserselectionstoarray.php

<html>
<h1>User Inputs</h1>

<?php

    $userselection = array(
        'Foldername1' => $_POST['Foldername1'],
        'selectMediaType1' => $_POST['selectMediaType1'],
        'selectClassificationType1' => $_POST['Foldername1'],
        'selectDispositionType1' => $_POST['selectClassificationType1'],
        'Group1' => $_POST['Group1'],
        'FileSeries1' => $_POST['FileSeries1'],
        'SubFileSeries1' => $_POST['SubFileSeries1'],   

    foreach($userselection1 as $userSelectionArrayDisplay1)  {

        echo "$userSelectionArrayDisplay1<br />";

        }

?>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the data to be displayed on a new page you can do so using an input box as a button and call a javascript function to display the data in a div that can be to the right of the dropdown.

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="yourFunction()">
```

When you use an input box with type "submit" it defaults to render a new page.
To have your javascript function display the data to the right it would look something like this:

```
function yourFunction() { 
  //#tableWrapper is the id of the div that you insert the table with the data into
  var displayData = document.getElementById("tableWrapper");
  displayData.innerHTML = "<table><tr><td>...."; //Put the data here
}
```

As for the dropdown problem. You could do something where you have three dropdowns Group, FileSeries, and SubFileSeries. You can make the last two disabled and when the Group is selected you can populate the FileSeries dropdown with the correct data and so on. Read this question for a good example: [By selecting from dropdown, enable another dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209665/by-selecting-from-dropdown-enable-another-dropdown)

Hope this helps.